# Whence this difference in supply current?

Tags: specifications

When I need a [MAX809](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/MAX809S-D.PDF) I prefer the OnSemi part over those from Maxim or NXP because the former has a much lower supply current. But I was looking at the [NXP datasheet](http://www.nxp.com/acrobat_download2/datasheets/MAX809_MAX810_3.pdf) again recently, and I noticed that there's a big difference in supply current depending on package:

> **SOT-23**
>   Typical: 24\$\mu\$A
>   Maximum: 60\$\mu\$A
>   **SC-70**
>   Typical: 24\$\mu\$A
>   Maximum: 35\$\mu\$A
>
> Compare with the **OnSemi** (both packages)
>   Typical: 0.8\$\mu\$A
>   Maximum: 1.8\$\mu\$A

So for the SOT-23 that's nearly double the SC-70's value. I realize that a SOT-23 can dissipate a bit more power than an SC-70, but these values are under the same temperature conditions. The [Maxim datasheet](http://datasheets.maxim-ic.com/en/ds/MAX803-MAX810Z.pdf) gives exactly the same figures, while OnSemi doesn't differentiate between packages.
How can this difference be explained?

Comment: It doesn't make sense :-).

Comment: @Russell - I'm glad I'm not the only one who thinks so. Yet, it's odd that two manufacturers publish exactly the same figures.

Comment: Any chance you purchased any of these and could tell us if the supply info actually seems to be correct?

Answer (score 2):

This difference could be explained in a number of ways, though none definitive without knowing more about the device than the datasheet (necessarily) reveals.  These may include differences between the actual structures of the underlying devices within the packaging (most likely), as well as differences in the estimations, testing practices, and / or acceptable margins of the companies or even specific engineers involved in their design and documentation.  It is conceivable that typos in the actual datasheets themselves could be blamed.  Nothing is certain until it can be proven that it works, and even then, things (manufacturing processes, etc) can change over time without you (or even the distributor, documentarian) necessarily being informed.  Good testing procedures, performed on all devices prior to distribution (i.e. quality control) and wide operational margins for parts selection can help to insulate you from problems inherent in both mis-specification and changes in manufacturing over time, but don't be surprised if your (initial) design requires re-work somewhere along the line because of these things.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, though I must add that I don't buy most of your arguments. Changes in processes for instance don't explain the large difference in current between packages. Neither do specific engineers in design and documentation; this will almost certainly be the same die, no different design. A typo is not impossible, but it's odd to find the same typo in the datasheets of two different manufacturers. You don't give a good explanation why there should be a 150 % difference in ground current when only the package is different.